# MS SQL Back up not restore the MS SQL 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new comer to MS SQL 2014. I will try restore db back up. but given following error. expect some expert help.

```
  TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Restore of database 'MSSQL_MED' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

------------------------------

Database 'MSSQL_MED' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because part or all of object 'Answer_statusComponent_signings_History' is enabled with data compression or vardecimal storage format. Data compression and vardecimal storage format are only supported on SQL Server Enterprise Edition.
Database 'MSSQL_MED' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because it contains a partition function 'archive_applog_pf'. Only Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports partitioning.
Database 'MSSQL_MED' cannot be started because some of the database functionality is not available in the current edition of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 909)
```

-------version info-------------------

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.14393
```

Comment: You are trying to restore a database that was backed up from a version of sql server that's Enterprise and is using Enterprise features like data compression - my guess is you are trying to restore this backup to either Standard or Express which don't support those Enterprise features until Sql 2016 SP1 - if possible, upgrade your 2014 edition to 2016 SP1

Comment: @ScottHodgin can you please,tell me how to upgrade this and i take this back up  from sql 2014. ?

Comment: Do you have access to the original server? If so, it might be possible to *remove* the "Enterprise" features (the data compression/partitioning) of the database, and back it up again. If you can't do that, then you'll need to find (or buy) a copy of 2014 Enterprise edition that supports these features.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to restore a database that was backed up from a version of sql server that's Enterprise and is using Enterprise features like data compression - my guess is you are trying to restore this backup to either Standard or Express which don't support those Enterprise features until Sql 2016 SP1 - if possible, upgrade your 2014 edition to 2016 SP1.

The steps involved in upgrading are too numerous for this Q/A environment.

If you decide to upgrade, check the information in this link [Upgrade SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622.aspx).  Additional information can be found by searching for

> **upgrade sql 2014 to 2016**

Sql 2016 SP1 has a number of features available in ALL Sql Server editions (Standard, Express, etc.) that used to be only available in Enterprise edition.  For more information on those new features, please check

[SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 (SP1) released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/)

Upgrading from one release of Sql Server to another needs planning and testing to prevent unexpected surprises.

Instead of upgrading the current Sql Server 2014 environment that you are trying to restore to, you might be better off installing a brand new Sql Server 2016 Express instance and applying SP1 to that new install.  Then restore your database to that new instance.  Be aware that Sql Server 2016 Express edition can only accommodate database sizes of 10GB, so depending on the size of the database you are trying to restore - that may limit your ability to use Sql Server Express

Comment: Be aware that if the database is larger than 10 GB pre-backup, then you won't be able to restore to Standard edition. If you are a developer, you may be eligible for the free developer edition which can use enterprise features (free in both 2014 and 2016 versions).